# Apply color coding to a specific class member or namespace?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, namespaces, resharper, color-coding

Is it possible using VS 2010 + ReSharper (or any other 3rd party plugins / extensions) to apply color coding a **specific** class member or namespace?

For example, let's say I have the following code that makes a breadcrumb item called "Home" using a hard-coded string literal:

```
var bcHome = new um.classes.Breadcrumb(um.nav.nodeIds.home,
            um.nav.nodeIds.root,
            "Home",
            um.bc.events.home);
```

In my editor I have strings colored as *magenta*, so they are easy to see.

Now I decide to make a **"um.tokens"** namespace for strings. I have something like this:

```
um.tokens = {
    "BREADCRUMB_HOME": "Home"
};
```

Finally, I update the original code block as follows:

```
var bcHome = new um.classes.Breadcrumb(um.nav.nodeIds.home,
            um.nav.nodeIds.root,
            um.tokens.BREADCRUMB_HOME,
            um.bc.events.home);
```

I want the IDE to display any members in **"um.tokens"** in *magenta*. How can I do this?

**EDIT** - In other words, how do I make **um.tokens.BREADCRUMB_HOME** appear in the same style as the quoted string literal *"Home"* ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Lesson learned. :-)